# FOCUS (Mainframe DBMS) Acronym: What Does It Stand For?

Tags: database, mainframe

Information Builders released mainframe database application FOCUS in 1975. You can read the whole story on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOCUS.

What does the acronym FOCUS stand for?

Comment: Did you contact the vendor and ask?

Comment: Hi Wayne, thank you; that is the obvious next step. FOCUS has its place in the pantheon of early databases; I thought a hoary mainframe veteran might recognize the name. Thanks again for your suggestion.

Comment: I followed-up with the vendor and inquired; I will share any reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, from the founder of the company:

"But they gave me something much more valuable, which was the computer time, and
they also gave me the computer terminals. So that’s what put me in business. I got a
little 1,000 square foot office in New York, and we divvyed up the $9,500 a month,
$1,000 went for the rent. I went to a small space specialist. He specialized in under
5,000 feet. He got me this place, and they whitewashed it totally white. I mean
lemon’s not going to do a whole lot for you. Today I can still look back on my
starting point, that’s true. I was President so I took so much a month, and Peter
took, and Marty took, and we had a sector, and we had two programmers part-time
who ran the program for American Information Services. **We labeled this program
FOCUS. I guess it stood for online computer users, but we needed was an acronym
that was easy to remember. So we gave it a computer type name, and FOCUS was
our term for this non-procedural language.** We got started about March 1, 1975.
American Can gave us our first check and we set up shop."

Link: http://docs.google.com/gview?a=v&q=cache:cN6NFyPWZzsJ:www.cwhonors.org/archives/histories/cohen.pdf+WebFOCUS+%2Bacronym+mainframe+%22information+builders%22&hl=en&gl=us&sig=AFQjCNFAMDVyVMp9IGM9tZxJiw_cVk-3cQ